# Obtain the Top Users within a Time Range MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to generate a report of the activities that users have done within a specific time range.

This is the structure of my table called "register", every time a user performs an action on the website, it will record in the table the ID of the user, the type of the action that user did, and the date, which is provided by the PHP function time().   The table looks like this:

```
iduser | Action | Date
82919  |  0     | 1339081680
89754  |  5     | 1339084560
88135  |  1     | 1339585320
82919  |  0     | 1339083420
26367  |  1     | 1349096510
```

I have used the following query to select the records that are within the time range:

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE date>='$BeginningDate' AND date<'$EndDate' ORDER BY date DESC
```

This query works wonderfully, but what I don't know now is how to write the query that besides generating the list of records that belong to the specific time range, will also calculate which were the top 10 users that have more records within that time.   I have tried writing subqueries, but that topic surpasses my current skills.

Comment: If the below response is acceptable, can you please mark it as the answer?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), iduser
FROM register 
WHERE date>='$BeginningDate' AND date<'$EndDate'
GROUP BY iduser
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Note that if the count is the same for multiple users in the "top 10", this will only take the first 10.  If you want something more complicated, you'll have to consider additional modifications.